# Infinimum of Sum of convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> Let $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $(f)^{m}_{k=1}$ be a family of convex functions $f_k: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Show that the function $f$ is convex.$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \ x \mapsto \inf{\{f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+...+f_m(x_m)|x_k\in \mathbb{R} \ x_1+x_2+...+x_k=x\}} $$

Given convex functions $f,g$ I have proven that their sum is also convex by: $$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2),\ g(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \leq tg(x_1)+(1-t)g(x_2) \implies $$
$$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)+g(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \leq \bigg(tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)\bigg) + \bigg( tg(x_1)+(1-t)g(x_2) \bigg) \implies $$
$$(f+g)\big(tx_1+(1-t)x_2 \big) \leq \big(tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)+tg(x_1)+(1-t)g(x_2)\big). $$

After this I'm having a tough time understanding what the infimum of a sum of multiple functions would change, what else would I have to show to prove the original statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x$ and $y$ let
$$x=x_1+\ldots +x_k,\quad y=y_1+\ldots +y_k$$ Then for $0\le t\le 1$ we get
$$(1-t)x+ty=u_1+\ldots +u_k,\qquad u_j=(1-t)x_j+ty_j$$
Thus by the convexity of each function $f_j$ we obtain$$f_1(u_1)+\ldots +f_k(u_k)\le (1-t)[f_1(x_1)+\ldots + f_k(x_k)]+ t[f_1(y_1)+\ldots +f_k(y_k)]$$
Therefore, as $f((1-t)x+ty)\le f_1(u_1)+\ldots +f_k(u_k),$ we get
$$f((1-t)x+ty)\le  (1-t)[f_1(x_1)+\ldots + f_k(x_k)]+ t[f_1(y_1)+\ldots +f_k(y_k)]$$
Taking the infimum over all representations of $x=x_1+\ldots +x_k$ and $y=y_1+\ldots +y_k$ we finally obtain
$$f((1-t)x+ty)\le  (1-t)f(x)+tf(y)$$